# Two codes using subprocess.run in for loop giving different results

Tags: python, for-loop, subprocess

I'm using python to generate multiple folders, copying fil ein them, and then use supbprocess.run in this folders.

I first tried the code below,

```
import os
import shutil
from xlrd import open_workbook
from xlutils.copy import copy
import subprocess


chemin=os.getcwd()+'\\'

for i in range(1,16):
    if os.path.exists("unitaire_"+str(i)):
        shutil.rmtree("unitaire_"+str(i))
    os.mkdir("unitaire_"+str(i))

chemin2=chemin+"\\DOC\\"

for file in os.listdir(chemin2):
    for i in range(1,16):
        shutil.copy(chemin2+file,chemin+"unitaire_"+str(i))

result_for_unit = open("result_for_unit.tb","r").readlines()
result_mom_unit = open("result_mom_unit.tb","r").readlines()

ligne_index = []

for n_ligne,lines_for in enumerate(result_for_unit) :
    lines_for = lines_for.split(" ")
    while " " in lines_for:
        lines_for.remove(" ")
    if "Load" in lines_for :
        ligne_index.append(n_ligne)

ligne_index.append(len(result_for_unit))

for i in range (1,16):
    chemin3 = chemin+"unitaire_"+str(i)+"\\"
    os.chdir(chemin3)
    
    if os.path.exists("result_for.tb"):
        os.remove("result_for.tb")
    result_for = open("result_for.tb","x")
    if os.path.exists("result_mom.tb"):
        os.remove("result_mom.tb")
    result_mom = open("result_mom.tb","x")
    result_for.write(" result_for                                                                                                                  Page 1"+"\n"+"\n"+" Analysis type         LINSTA"+"\n")
    if i ==1:
        k=2
    else :
        k=ligne_index[i-1]
    while k<ligne_index[i]-2:
        result_for.write(result_for_unit[k])
        result_mom.write(result_mom_unit[k])
        k+=1
    result_for.write('\n')
    result_mom.write('\n')
    result_for.write('\n')
    result_mom.write('\n')
    result_mom.write('stop')
    result_for.write('stop')    

    subprocess.run(['python',"IN_230320_105.py"])
    subprocess.run(['python',"FERRAILLE_230320_105.py"])
    subprocess.run(['python',"IN_230320_150.py"])
    subprocess.run(['python',"FERRAILLE_230320_150.py"])
```

But i didn't get the wanted results (as if while running the files "IN_230320_105.py" the files result_for and reult_mom was modified, whereas the code "IN_230320_105.py don't do such thing)

So i tried something else, with subprocess.run in another loop like so :

```
for i in range (1,16):
chemin3 = chemin+"unitaire_"+str(i)+"\\"
os.chdir(chemin3)

if os.path.exists("result_for.tb"):
    os.remove("result_for.tb")
result_for = open("result_for.tb","x")
if os.path.exists("result_mom.tb"):
    os.remove("result_mom.tb")
result_mom = open("result_mom.tb","x")
result_for.write(" result_for                                                                                                                  Page 1"+"\n"+"\n"+" Analysis type         LINSTA"+"\n")
if i ==1:
    k=2
else :
    k=ligne_index[i-1]
while k<ligne_index[i]-2:
    result_for.write(result_for_unit[k])
    result_mom.write(result_mom_unit[k])
    k+=1
result_for.write('\n')
result_mom.write('\n')
result_for.write('\n')
result_mom.write('\n')
result_mom.write('stop')
    result_for.write('stop')

for i in range (1,16):
    chemin3 = chemin+"unitaire_"+str(i)+"\\"
    os.chdir(chemin3)   

    subprocess.run(['python',"IN_230320_105.py"])
    subprocess.run(['python',"FERRAILLE_230320_105.py"])
    subprocess.run(['python',"IN_230320_150.py"])
    subprocess.run(['python',"FERRAILLE_230320_150.py"])
```

And now, there is no more problems. (the begining of the script is the same)

So, my question is, why do i have a different behavior with this two codes ?

Thanks for all readers, hoping some of you can give me an explanation !

Comment: Your question is not straightforward. What is the expected output? What errors do you get? We need a minimal reproducible example to reproduce the behaviour you observe. Please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: To pull out the relevant parts of the [mre] definition: We need the **shortest possible code** that someone can run themselves (without needing changes -- missing data files, hardcoded storage locations, etc) to see your problem and test proposed fixes. If nobody but you can see the problem, nobody but you can test proposed answers. A more clearly-defined question also is easier for others to learn from, and thus a more helpful entry overall in the [long-tail FAQ that Stack Overflow exists to build](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/05/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/).

Comment: @alec_djinn Thank you for your answer, i'll try to reproduce it in a script with input i can share

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, thank you for your answer and your advices

Comment: General advice: you're using the complication of `subprocess` to call another Python script; consider importing the Python code as a module and calling the functions of interest directly.